# representing significant and non-significant paths of SEM with different line types in r

Tags: r

[SEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE0bB.png)

In the SEM I have attached, the path from "Altitude" to "Tree species diversity" is not significant. I would like to represent the significant paths with solid lines and non-significant paths with dashed lines. Anyone provide me the code in r for this?